# Read JSON in Java Script

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I created a JSON variable and parsing it to JSON. But I am not able to read the values. I tried everything. But its not working. Here is my JavaScript code.

```
var graph='{"graphSpace":[{"rectangle":{"minX":0.0,"minY":0.0,"maxX":0.0,"maxY":0.0},"contents":"","rights":[],"lefts":[],"tops":[],"downs":[],"annotation":{"id":255,"type":"line"}],[{"rectangle":{"minX":174.0,"minY":87.0,"maxX":989.0,"maxY": 136.0},"contents":"Carter Brothers Fire u0026 Life Safety","rights":[{"id":59}],"lefts":[],"tops":[{"id":255}],"downs":[{"id":14},{"id":16},{"id":19},{"id":21},{"id":28},{"id":31},{"id":33},{"id":35},{"id":42},{"id":45},{"id":47},{"id":49},{"id":52},{"id":183},{"id":169},{"id":199},{"id":190},{"id":201},{"id":192},{"id":208},{"id":215},{"id":230},{"id":233},{"id":240},{"id":243},{"id":246}],"annotation":{"id":7,"type":"line"}},{"rectangle":{"minX":2073.0,"minY":92.0,"maxX":2327.0,"maxY":150.0},"contents":"Invoice","rights":[],"lefts":[{"id":7}],"tops":[{"id":7},{"id":255}],"downs":[{"id":67},{"id":70},{"id":72},{"id":74},{"id":76},{"id":100},{"id":102},{"id":105},{"id":108},{"id":111},{"id":114},{"id":135},{"id":160},{"id":151},{"id":162},{"id":153},{"id":264},{"id":280},{"id":302}],"annotation":{"id":59,"type":"line"}}]}';
```

For your convenience, I'll put the data in a readable format.

```
    {
   "graphSpace":
    [
        {"rectangle":
            "{  "minX": 0.0,  "minY": 0.0,  "maxX": 0.0,  "maxY":0.0}",
        "contents":"",
        "rights":"[]",
        "lefts":"[]",
        "tops":"[]",
        "downs":"[]",
        "annotation":
            "{  "id": 255,  "type": "line"}"
    ],
    [
        {"rectangle":
            "{  "minX": 174.0,  "minY": 87.0,  "maxX": 989.0,  "maxY": 136.0}",
        "contents":"JSON u0026 JAVASCRIPT",
        "rights":"
            [{"id":59}]",
        "lefts":"[]",
        "tops":"[{"id":255}]",
        "downs":"
            [{"id":14},]",
        "annotation":
            "{  "id": 7,  "type": "line"}"
        },
        {"rectangle":
            "{  "minX": 2073.0,  "minY": 92.0,  "maxX": 2327.0, "maxY":150.0}",
        "contents":"JSON EXample",
        "rights":"[]",
        "lefts":
            "[{"id":7}]",
        "tops":
            "[{"id":7},{"id":255}]",
        "downs":
            "[{"id":67},{"id":70},{"id":72},]",
        "annotation":
            "{"id": 59,  "type": "line"}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am creating a variable which will store the parsed data.
Then I am checking whether it stored or not. So i am reading the first value and alerting it.

```
var graphSpace=JSON.parse(graph);
var minx = graphSpace[0].rectangle.minX;
alert(minx);
```

But when i open this JSP page, I am not able to get see that alert. What is the mistake here?

**Update: Sorry I forgot to add the first key when I was copying. Please check it**

Comment: if this is code then you have mis-spell `alert`

Comment: Oh! Sorry when I typed here, I made the mistake. In my code it is correctly spelled.

Comment: What error are you seeing? what is the value that actually gets assigned to `graphSpace`? Is it an array? Does it have a 0'th element? Does that element have a .rectangle property? Does *that*   property have a .minX property? There's a world of debugging you need to do before posting a question like this. The largest problem may be that that isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid format

Comment: If you can use jQuery, you can try jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).  You might also want to make sure your browser supports `JSON.parse`.  And the best way to get to the bottom of what's happening is to use a debugger like FireBug.  My first question is: "are there errors in the console?"  Like @meagar says, you need to take some basic debugging steps before asking this question here.  It will save you tons of time in the future to learn how to debug now.

Comment: Please use a Javascript console or debugging tool. You have a syntax error in your JSON string.

Comment: json key a hash object with the format `{key: value}`, yours is not

Comment: I'm sure there are online JSON validators, too... let me do a quick google... Wow, that was easy: [Please validate here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jsonlint.com to crrect your json.com. After correction it will be like this. Gve suitable name to LEVEL 1 and LEVEL for  the key

```
{
    "LEVEL 1": [
        {
            "rectangle": {
                "minX": 0,
                "minY": 0,
                "maxX": 0,
                "maxY": 0
            },
            "contents": "",
            "rights": "[]",
            "lefts": "[]",
            "tops": "[]",
            "downs": "[]",
            "annotation": {
                "id": 255,
                "type": "line"
            }
        }
    ],
    "LEVEL 11": [
        {
            "rectangle": {
                "minX": 174,
                "minY": 87,
                "maxX": 989,
                "maxY": 136
            },
            "contents": "JSON u0026 JAVASCRIPT",
            "rights": {
                "id": 59
            },
            "lefts": "[]",
            "tops": {
                "id": 255
            },
            "downs": {
                "id": 14
            },
            "annotation": {
                "id": 7,
                "type": "line"
            }
        },
        {
            "rectangle": {
                "minX": 2073,
                "minY": 92,
                "maxX": 2327,
                "maxY": 150
            },
            "contents": "JSON EXample",
            "rights": "[]",
            "lefts": {
                "id": 7
            },
            "tops": {
                "id": 7
            },
            "you2": {
                "id": 255
            },
            "downs": [
                {
                    "id": 67
                },
                {
                    "id": 70
                },
                {
                    "id": 72
                }
            ],
            "annotation": {
                "id": 59,
                "type": "line"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid format. Remove curly braces that wrap your array.

```js
 var graph='[{"rectangle":{"minX":0.0,"minY":0.0,"maxX":0.0,"maxY":0.0},"contents":"","rights":[],"lefts":[],"tops":[],"downs":[],"annotation":{"id":255,"type":"line"}],[{"rectangle":{"minX":174.0,"minY":87.0,"maxX":989.0,"maxY": 136.0},"contents":"Carter Brothers Fire u0026 Life Safety","rights":[{"id":59}],"lefts":[],"tops":[{"id":255}],"downs":[{"id":14},{"id":16},{"id":19},{"id":21},{"id":28},{"id":31},{"id":33},{"id":35},{"id":42},{"id":45},{"id":47},{"id":49},{"id":52},{"id":183},{"id":169},{"id":199},{"id":190},{"id":201},{"id":192},{"id":208},{"id":215},{"id":230},{"id":233},{"id":240},{"id":243},{"id":246}],"annotation":{"id":7,"type":"line"}},{"rectangle":{"minX":2073.0,"minY":92.0,"maxX":2327.0,"maxY":150.0},"contents":"Invoice","rights":[],"lefts":[{"id":7}],"tops":[{"id":7},{"id":255}],"downs":[{"id":67},{"id":70},{"id":72},{"id":74},{"id":76},{"id":100},{"id":102},{"id":105},{"id":108},{"id":111},{"id":114},{"id":135},{"id":160},{"id":151},{"id":162},{"id":153},{"id":264},{"id":280},{"id":302}],"annotation":{"id":59,"type":"line"}}]';
```

After that all will be right.

Comment: are you sure? won't this make two arrays, with a comma between them, which is invalid?

Comment: Good catch InviS, there are several other issues with it though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your JSON is valid?

Use this site to check:
http://jsonlint.com/

It's telling me there's an issue with your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This format is invalid. The outmost {} is unneeded and remove the quotes around embedded object like:

```
"rectangle": "{  "minX": 174.0,  "minY": 87.0,  "maxX": 989.0,  "maxY": 136.0}",
```

Instead:

```
"rectangle": {  "minX": 174.0,  "minY": 87.0,  "maxX": 989.0,  "maxY": 136.0},
```

Comment: *... remove the quotes around the variable names ...* You mean like `'{[{rectangle:{minX:0.0,minY:0.0,...`?

Comment: ... I mean the inner objects. They need no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid. Properties of objects in JSON need to be listed as name:value pairs, but you haven't done this for the outermost object. Since you seem to want this to be an array, I'd suggest changing the outermost braces to square brackets.